# Top bar Achievements popup feels lonely with only one total

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, reputation, top-bar, achievements-dialog

[image]

The `Today` group has a nice useful total.

However, once 0:00 UTC rolls around, I can no longer see my score for yesterday.
Please add a total for the `Yesterday` and `Last 7 days` groups.

On a broader note, how can you have a button with an icon of two graphs open a popup that never has any graphs?

Comment: The total for "today" only shows up if there's only one site with changes today - we don't show totals for the other sections because they would a) be multi-site and b) not be accurate due to the way we fetch the data.

Comment: @NickCraver: If there are multiple sites, the totals only show when the group is collapsed.  That's fine; I just want numbers to be there.

Comment: The numbers would not be accurate for users for differing periods based on the activity of the user - the last group would always be off and possibly the one before it.  We fetch the last `n` records when building this dropdown, so for very active users the total wouldn't even be correct for the last 7 days.

Comment: @NickCraver: So you don't even have enough data for `Yesterday`?

Comment: Yesterday would usually be safe for the activity of the top users right now, beyond that definitely wouldn't be - the total would be a moving window all over the place.  We grab the last 250 `<> 0` rep changes for the account currently.

Comment: So can you at least add a total for yesterday? You might also want to change `7` to the actual number of days covered.

Comment: Also, that means that anyone who gets >3950 rep in one day will get an inaccurate count.

Comment: Possibly for yesterday - I'd personally like the breakdowns there as well but was shot down last time...will bring it up on today's team call.

Comment: @SLaks untrue. With 250 rep changes, you could be awarded a whopping 125k reputation if it is 250 awarded +500 bounties.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

While the older ones aren't really feasible for a few reasons, yesterday makes a lot of sense.

Starting with the next build, it'll have the same summary/breakdown behavior that the today section does.

Comment: [Small bug](http://i.stack.imgur.com/47ZPK.png). (tooltip of yesterday is showing "today")

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd well then, another build coming up.

Comment: You're generous with your builds, just a couple of weeks ago we had to wait for days!

Comment: I was hoping the old totals could be included and found this answer. Can you please expand on why the older totals aren't really feasible here so I don't have to make a duplicate-ish post?

Comment: @TravisJ because we don't query to a window, we query to a count which means the window varies by activity level, making totals very inconsistent and the last bucket an unknown